# Laravel 6.5.1 migration Errno: Syntax error or access violation 1064

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I tried to do the migration and I ran into this error: Syntax error or access violation 1064. I looked at other similar problems but I couldn't find the solution to this problem. Please help, and thanks in advance.

```
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id');
           $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors')->onDelete('cascade');
           $table->string('title');
           $table->text('excerpt');
           $table->longText('body');
           $table->binary('post_image');
           $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
           $table->timestamps();
           $table->softDeletes();
        }); 


        Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->string('fist_name');
           $table->string('last_name');
           $table->binary('pic')->nullable();
           $table->timestamps();
           $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is one single migration creating both tables. Which would, in my opinion, not the best idea. Better to separate each table into its own migration.
Try to switch both of the creation blocks. So that before anything about the `posts`-table is done the `authors`-table is already created.

Because you are trying to set a foreign key from the `posts`-table to not yet created `authors`-table but both of them have to exist.

I also tend to separate foreign key constraints from the actual structure of a table for a better overview. But this would be thing of personal opinion.

```php
    Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->string('fist_name');
           $table->string('last_name');
           $table->binary('pic')->nullable();
           $table->timestamps();
           $table->softDeletes();
        });

    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id');
           $table->string('title');
           $table->text('excerpt');
           $table->longText('body');
           $table->binary('post_image');
           $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
           $table->timestamps();
           $table->softDeletes();

           $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Hope that this can help a bit.

Comment: The tables are on different pages but now I'll try some of the suggestions you provide.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Danaq, I changed the order of creation. I created the "author" table first then the "posts" and it worked like a charm.